# Anonymous functions in PHP

Tags: php

I'm developing a web scraper for the Android Play Store in PHP, and i have some trouble.
This is the function i use to get app comments:

```
function reviews($url_to_crawl , $crawler)  {
        $reviews_contents = array();
        if (num_reviews($url_to_crawl, $crawler)) {
                $crawler->filter('.review-body')->each(function(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler $node, $i) use ($reviews_contents) {
            $reviews_contents[$i] = trim($node->text());
            });
        }
        return $reviews_contents;
 }
```

now `$reviews_contents` is empty, i guess because i use an anonymous function. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the variable `$reviews_contents` by [reference](http://php.net/manual/language.references.pass.php) in the `use` like this

```
function(Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler $node, $i) use (&$reviews_contents)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `use` in anonymous functions passes variables by value instead of by reference. You want a reference so you can modify the variable and have those modifications stick around after the function gets called.

```
function (Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler $node, $i) use (&$reviews_contents) {
   // modifications to `$reviews_contents` will stick around because it's now
   // a reference, not passed by value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting & before $reviews_contents like below to get a reference to that variable ...

```
use (&$reviews_contents)
```